# Java - Two-dimensional array declaration issue

Tags: java, arrays, intellij-idea

I have just declared a two-dimensional array in my program:

```
String[][] choices = new String[4][];
choices[0] = new String[10];
choices[1] = new String[20];
choices[2] = new String[20];
choices[3] = new String[20];
```

However, IntelliJ Idea, the IDE I am currently using, threw out a bunch of errors starting from the second line. What is wrong with my code? I have checked other questions regarding two-dimensional arrays and found the exact same syntax being used.

**EDIT:** Based on my code above, I want the arrays to be of different length. Is that possible to make?

Comment: You might want to read the errors

Comment: Your code is completely fine. I just pasted it into IntelliJ and ran it.

Comment: Make sure you wrote this code in a method and not just in the class.

Comment: Care to share what the errors are? Also you might want to add some more of the surrounding code (e.g. class and method declaration).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code snippet works fine, and you can have inner String arrays of different length, e.g.:

```
String[][] choices = new String[2][];
choices[0] = new String[1];
choices[1] = new String[2];
choices[0][0] = "Foo";
choices[1][0] = "Bar";
choices[1][1] = "Baz";

System.out.println(choices[0][0] + " " + choices[1][0] + " " + choices[1][1]);
```

[Ideone demonstration](http://ideone.com/La1TO9).

In short, your problem is elsewhere. Read the errors since that's what they're for. They're often descriptive enough.